# These Array Formulas don't work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Both of the following array "if or" formulas work in Google Sheets, but not in Excel. Can you help me rewrite them to work in Excel.

```
=ArrayFormula(if({or(
            Plans!$E$2:$E$9=R2,Plans!$F$2:$F$9=R2,Plans!$G$2:$G$7=R2,
            Plans!$H$2:$H$7=R2,Plans!$I$2:$I$3=R2,Plans!$J$2=R2)},
            $AA$1,$Z$1))

=ARRAYFORMULA(if(or(R2=Plans!$E$2:$J$2),
               Plans!$A$2,if(or(Plans!$E$3:$I$3=R2),Plans!$A$3,
               if(or(Plans!$E$4:$H$4=R2),Plans!$A$4,
               if(or(Plans!$E$8:$F$8=R2),Plans!$A$8," ")))))
```

I'm sure just the first one being fixed will help me fix the second one.

Comment: Is there something that prevents us from using the single, contiguous range E2:J9? That is, can the value in R2 occur in cells within that range which are NOT being referenced in your current formula, i.e. G8:G9, H8:H9, I4:I9, J3:J9, and so might produce an erroneous result?

Comment: @XORLX If the value is not found in the range then it should give a false field which is z1 that has a specific value. The issue was that arrays are treated differently in google sheets as compared to mac or windows excel. Jonathan' was able to correct my mistake. Thanks for looking at the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array formulae in Excel:

- don't use =ArrayFormula; and
- have to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter (you can't enter the curly brackets yourself)

All you need to do is to remove 'ArrayFormula()' and, after typing it in, press Ctrl+Alt+Enter. If you click on the cell again and look at it, you will see curly brackets in the formula bar.

You type

```
=if(or(Plans!$E$2:$E$9=R2,Plans!$F$2:$F$9=R2,Plans!$G$2:$G$7=R2,
        Plans!$H$2:$H$7=R2,Plans!$I$2:$I$3=R2,Plans!$J$2=R2),
        $AA$1,$Z$1)
```

and click Ctrl+Shift+Enter; Excel will return:

```
{=if(or(Plans!$E$2:$E$9=R2,Plans!$F$2:$F$9=R2,Plans!$G$2:$G$7=R2,
        Plans!$H$2:$H$7=R2,Plans!$I$2:$I$3=R2,Plans!$J$2=R2),
        $AA$1,$Z$1)}
```

Comment: Thanks you were able to lead me to the correct answer. I used a mac so the key combinations was CONTROL + SHIFT + ENTER.

It helped me with this complex formula, so i really appreciate it. 

=if(B2=$AA$1,ARRAYFORMULA(if(left(U2,2)="Mr",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,MrExports!$L$2:$R$2597,7,0),""),if(left(V2,2)="Ms",iferror(VLOOKUP(A2,MsExports!$L$2:$R$3300,7,0),""),VLOOKUP(A2,SUBIDS!$A$2:$C$17861,3,0)))),"")